# AWS IVS - getMetricData Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hey i am using getmetricdata to fetch metrics ConcurrentViews namespace AWS/IVS it is providing me output as `The values are [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0] The timestamps are [Wed Feb 14 14:12:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:11:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:10:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:09:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:08:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:07:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:06:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:05:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:04:00 UTC 2024, Wed Feb 14 14:03:00 UTC 2024]`
Note that it is giving me after 1 minute. But i want views after every 10 seconds. I am using metricsStat as 
  `MetricStat metStat = new MetricStat();`
  `metStat.setStat("Maximum");<br/>`
  `metStat.setPeriod(10);<br/>`
  `metStat.setMetric(met);`
`

I want MAXIMUM views of **every ** 10 seconds